# Table is overlap with other column

Tags: tables

I want to make table (using multirow and multicolumn). I want "Variable Influence" and "Description" is vertically centered and I don't want first column and last column is overlap with others column (even though I use tabularx). How to change it?

This is my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm, top=2.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
    \FloatBarrier
    \begin{table}[h]
        \caption{The Results of Discrimination Tests on Government Institution $X$ and Educational Institution $X$}
        \centering
        \label{tab6}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXXXXXX}
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Variable Influence}}&
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Goverment Institution $X$}}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Educational Institution $X$}}&\textbf{discrimination test results}&\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Description}}\\
            \cline{2-6}
            &\textbf{Coefficient Path}&\textit{\textbf{Standard Error}}&\textbf{Coefficient Path}&\textit{\textbf{Standard Error}}&\textbf{P-value}&\\
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
    \FloatBarrier
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\multirow{2}{=}{\textbf{Variable Influence}}` should work for the first column.

Comment: Yes, but it is not vertically centered.

Comment: Vertically center with respect to the text above and below the line?

Comment: Please also clarify: Do you explicitly want your table columns to have equal widths? Will your columns contain text that needs linebreaks or did you just use `tabularx` to get the linebreaks in the column headers?

Comment: Yes, I want the column width is equal. The "Variable Influence"  is vertically center with respect to the text above and below the line, and and "Description" is respect to line.

Comment: I need tabularx for linebreaking all contains in my table (Header and contain).

Comment: `\multirow{4}{=}{\textbf{Variable Influence}}`  should fix the problem with the first column header. However, fixing the problem with the overlap in the sixth/seventh column header is harder since the word "discrimination" is too long. Would you allow hyphenating this word?

Comment: Yes, I allow the hyphenation for "discrimination" word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are four different versions of your table using slightly different layouts. The captions of each table contain a breif description of how the respective layout was achieved:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm, top=2.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

%% Only used for second example

\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}

%% Only used for third + fourth example
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[h]
        \caption{With the help of tabularx, hyphenation of "discrimination"}
        \centering
        \label{tab6}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{7}{X}}
            \hline
            \multirow{6}{=}{\textbf{Variable Influence}}&
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Goverment Institution $X$}}&
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Educational Institution $X$}}&
            \hspace{0pt}\textbf{discrimination test results}&
            \multirow{6}{=}{\textbf{Description}}\\
            \cline{2-6}
            &\textbf{Coefficient Path}&
            \textit{\textbf{Standard Error}}&
            \textbf{Coefficient Path}&
            \textit{\textbf{Standard Error}}&
            \textbf{P-value}&\\
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}


  \begin{table}[h]
        \caption{Without tabularx, manual linebreaks with makecell, }
        \centering
        \label{tab6}
        \begin{tabular}{*{7}{c}}
            \hline
            \multirow{4}{*}{\thead{Variable\\ Influence}}&
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Goverment\\ Institution $X$}}&
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Educational\\ Institution $X$}}&
            \thead{discrimination\\ test results}&
            \multirow{4}{*}{\thead{Description}}\\
            \cline{2-6}
            &\thead{Coefficient\\ Path}&
            \itshape\thead{Standard\\ Error}&
            \thead{Coefficient\\ Path}&
            \itshape\thead{Standard\\ Error}&
            \thead{P-value}&\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

  \begin{table}[h]
  \renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalfont}
        \caption{Without tabularx, lines from booktabs, manual linebreaks in column headers with tabularx}
        \centering
        \label{tab6}
        \begin{tabular}{*{7}{c}}
            \toprule
            \multirow{4}{*}{\thead{Variable\\ Influence}}&
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Goverment\\ Institution $X$}}&
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Educational\\ Institution $X$}}&
            \thead{discrimination\\ test results}&
            \multirow{4}{*}{\thead{Description}}\\
            \cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(l){6-6}
            &\thead{Coefficient\\ Path}&
            \itshape\thead{Standard\\ Error}&
            \thead{Coefficient\\ Path}&
            \itshape\thead{Standard\\ Error}&
            \thead{P-value}&\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}[h]
        \caption{Equal column widths with tabularx, lines with booktabs}
        \centering
        \label{tab6}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{7}{X}}
            \toprule
            \multirow{6}{=}{Variable Influence}&
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{Goverment Institution $X$}&
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{Educational Institution $X$}&
            \hspace{0pt}discrimination test results&
            \multirow{6}{=}{Description}\\
            \cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(l){6-6}
            &Coefficient Path&
            Standard Error&
            Coefficient Path&
            Standard Error&
            P-value&\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me! It is very complete answer.